# Custom progress dialog

Tags: android, dialog, android-progressbar

How would I do a custom "loading" dialog during an `AsyncTask` like the one in the Bank of America app, for instance? See:

[image]

I basically don't want the popup `ProgressDialog` but instead one that is embedded into the layout.

Comment: Here is an example of a ProgressBar - http://codehenge.net/blog/2011/06/android-development-tutorial-progressbar-example/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a `ProgressDialog`. It's just a `ProgressBar`. Put it on your layout and make it visible when it's necessary.

Answer (score 2):

That's a ProgressBar view that can be added to any layout:

```
<ProgressBar
  android:indeterminate="true"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
/>
```